# Отправка данных SOAP в Jquery

Tags: jquery, soap

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь отправить данные через SOAP службе. В результате получаю Bad request. Код приведён ниже. Просьба помочь.

```
    var t = 'POST /url HTTP/1.1\
    Host: http://localhost:8008/C_M_Service\
    Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\
    Content-length: 350\
    SoapAction: http://localhost:8008/C_M_Service/GetCars\
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">\
    <soap:Body>\
      <GetCars xmlns="http://localhost:8008/C_M_Service/GetCars">\
        <id>123</id>\
      </GetCars>\
    </soap:Body>\
  </soap:Envelope>';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8008/C_M_Service/GetCars",
        datatype: "xml",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
        data: t,
        processData: false,
        error: function (err) {
            alert("Error:"+err.toString());
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#content").html(data);                   
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Полный текст запроса передавать не надо. Дополнительные заголовки добавляйте в `headers`. Попробуйте так:

```
var t = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">\
           <soap:Body>\
             <GetCars xmlns="http://localhost:8008/C_M_Service/GetCars">\
               <id>123</id>\
             </GetCars>\
           </soap:Body>\
         </soap:Envelope>';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:8008/C_M_Service/GetCars",
      datatype: "xml",
      type: "POST",
      headers: { "SOAPAction": "http://localhost:8008/C_M_Service/GetCars" },
      contentType: "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
      data: t,
      processData: false,
      error: function (err) {
        alert("Error:"+err.toString());
      },
      success: function (data) {
        $("#content").html(data);                   
      }
    });
});
```

ЗЫ Access-Control-Allow-Origin у вас прописан, надеюсь? RTFM [CORS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Попробовал сделать так, как Вы предложили - Bad request. Добавил в JQuery-запрос "crossDomain: true," - аналогично.

Comment: @AN90 смотрите в консоли нет ли там ошибки. и на закладке network в firebug'е правильно ли формируется запрос. / К сожалению у меня нет доступного веб-сервиса с прописанным Access-Control-Allow-Origin, а публичные веб-сервисы обычно не прописывают этот заголовок, соответственно через ajax к ним не достучаться...

Comment: Юрий, в консоли ничего нет. В Fiddler по запросу отображается следующее:                                                                                              POST http://localhost:8008/C_M_Service/GetCars HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: http://localhost:8008/C_M_Service/GetCars
Referer: http://localhost:61327/
Accept-Language: ru-RU
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Host: localhost:8008
Content-Length: 309
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

Comment: Плюс данные SOAP. По поводу Access-Control-Allow-Origin: у меня идёт обращение к WCF-службе, хостом для которой является Windows-служба. В App.config добавил следующее:                <system.webServer>
 <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:61327/" />
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS" />
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>

Comment: Хорошо, значит запрос до сервера по крайней мере доходит. Теперь надо разбираться с сервером, что ему не нравится в вашем запросе. Может быть сам текст запроса некорректный. Попробуйте в fiddler'е сначала отладить запрос (там есть закладка Composer, знаете наверное). т.е. чтоб текст был один в один и ответ вы получали. / Кстати есть [плагин jquery.soap](https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap), он сам envelope генерит. попробуйте его использовать. В общем надо локализовать в какой месте ошибка...

Comment: Попробовал в Fiddler использовать вкладку Composer. Указал метод POST, адрес метода службы, в Request Body поместил то, что отсылалось через JQuery-запрос (вкдадка Inspectors->Raw). Получил "HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/octet-stream' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.".

Comment: По поводу JQuery.soap: уже пробовал. Пользовался версией 1.6.4. Запрос:  $.soap({
            url: "http://localhost:8008/C_M_Service",
            method: "/GetCars",
            contentType: "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
            data: "<id>123</id>",
            error: function (soapresponse) {
                alert(soapresponse.toString());
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert("OK "+result.toString());
            }
        });

Comment: Получаю "HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.".

Comment: В случае fiddler'а вы указали не тот `contentType` (видимо вы взяли запрос, который указан у вас в вопросе), должен быть `application/soap+xml`. / В случае `$.soap` для вашего `contentType`, достаточно указать `soap12:true` в параметрах, вместо `contentType` (которое будет проигнорировано просто).

Comment: У меня указан тип application/soap+xml. Для запроса JQuery.soap добавил soap12:true, убрал ContentType. Получил: в alert - "Сообщение содержит неверный или просроченный токен контекста безопасности. Сообщение не было обработано", в fiddler - HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: @AN90 ну продвижение  происходит. 500 - означает, что дальше надо на сервере смотреть чего он ожидает. видимо, нужно как-то авторизоваться сначала. В зависимости от вебсервиса это может быть и form-based authentication и NTLM и проч варианты. Двигаться надо в направлении формирования правильных заголовков. С текстом запроса скорее всего проблем нет и клиентская сторона (сам javascript код) на данный момент сделала все, что могла.

Comment: Юрий, большое спасибо за ответы! А не должен ли в SOAP-сообщении быть тэг метода? У меня JQuery.soap его не добавляет. У меня возникают сомнения относительно правильности сформированного сообщения. Может ли сообщение оказаться некорректным для WCF? То есть именно на стороне сервера.

Comment: Посмотрите [пример](https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap/tree/master/web) для $.soap, там все параметры можно протестировать, кстати. И SOAPAction (вы про него?) тоже там надо заполнять... Судя по ошибке, которую вы привели выше, нужна авторизация. С веб-сервисами всегда так, надо понять что ему не нравится и попытаться удовлетворить его. Посоветовать что-то более конкретное тут сложно, надо тестить.